# Display bootstrap hover dropdown at right

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I learn about this plugin :
https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown

There is some options (HTML attributes) such as : data-hover="dropdown" ,data-toggle="dropdown" , ...

However i cannot find an option to display dropdown list at right of list trigger element .

For example : data-placement="right" or ="left".

[This demo](http://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/#) shows only left placement :

[image]

---

## Indeed, i want to be like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `.dropdown-menu-right`. The `.pull-right` utility is deprecated as of 3.1.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
...
</ul>
```

See [Alignment Options](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment) in Bootstrap docs.

Answer (score 0):

Add class **pull-right** for `ul.dropdown-menu`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"> ... </ul>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hqxcC/1/